# *** ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied')) when trying to upload files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, ssl, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am testing my app using `dev_appserver.py`.

My function to upload files looks something like:

```
def upload_file(file_stream, filename):
    """Upload a file to Google Cloud Storage."""

    client = google.cloud.storage.client.Client(project=_GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET)  # Here it breaks!

    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_string(file_stream)

    url = blob.public_url

    return url
```

At the line `bucket = client.get_bucket(_GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET)` I receive an error saying:

```
*** ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I authenticated by doing:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not set the proper permissions to access your Cloud Storage bucket from the account you are using to run your app.

The bucket' permissions are set through the use of [Access Control Lists](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) (ACLs), which define which accounts can access to the bucket and the kind of access (read, write, etc.) they have.

This is an example on how to set permissions to a particular account so it can access a bucket:

```
gsutil acl ch -u [USER_EMAIL]:[PERMISSION] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

There are other available options for setting ACLs, like using the Console or adding permissions through your code. You can find these options [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists).

**UPDATE**:

After doing some research and consulting with the team handling this kind of situations, I can confirm that [the use of SSL with sockets is not supported on dev_appserver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support#working_on_dev_appserver) as of this moment. As the client library you are using is using HTTPS for connections, without this support, using dev_appserver would not work.

As an alternative, you may consider using the [API client library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/). Here you can find an [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/storage/api-client) on how to use this library to connect to a Cloud Storage bucket from your app.

Comment: I am the owner of the Google Cloud project, so by default I also have the highest level of permission in the default bucket (which is the one I am using). I just double-checked and I have the following permissions: "Read and write access to existing buckets with object listing/creation/deletion.".

Comment: There are a couple of things you may try to check if this problem persists. First, try uploading the same files to a different bucket, this will confirm if the issue is specific to a particular bucket. If that is not the case, add a new role to your user account through the "IAM & Admin" menu in the Console, selecting the "roles/storage.admin" role, that will give the account full control over storage buckets and objects.

Comment: Note that this problem only ever happens in dev (via dev_appserver.py). Once the project is live in prod, the update function works just fine.

Comment: If that is the case, could you please confirm if there are significant differences for your uploads between the dev and the prod versions? Could you please update the question with any relevant information regarding the file uploads in prod?

Comment: I don't know if you have already tried the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) that allows you to test an upload to your default storage [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket), but just in case I will leave the links here. Please let me know if you are having issues with this tutorial as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional information regarding this subject. Please check it out and confirm if this information is useful for you.